# How do i get Show Times from JSon Phone 8.1

Tags: json, windows-phone-8.1

I have managed to get me class spot on now for encoding from json but I am as unsure as to how to select the showtimes element that is within  FetchTiming element I have my class constructed as so with help of json2csharp speicifically the list for FetchTiming

```
public class MovieDetails
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string secondry_images { get; set; }
        public string actor { get; set; }
        public string actoress { get; set; }
        public string director { get; set; }
        public string music_director { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
        public string age_restriction { get; set; }
        public string box_office { get; set; }
        public string official_site { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string writers { get; set; }
        public int imdb { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string created { get; set; }
        public string modified { get; set; }
        public string movie_category_id { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string movie_show_time_id { get; set; }
        public string theatre_movie_screen_id { get; set; }
        public string videous { get; set; }
        public string videos { get; set; }
        public string comming_soon { get; set; }
        public int avg { get; set; }
        public string movie_details_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class FetchTiming
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string theater_name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public List<string> show_times { get; set; }
        public string screen_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDetail
    {
        public MovieDetails movie_details { get; set; }
        public List<FetchTiming> fetch_timing { get; set; }
    }
```

}

Json Data

> {"movie_details":{"id":"1","name":"movie 1","description":"movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/harley3.jpg","secondry_images":"movie/Jellyfish.jpg,movie/Koala.jpg,movie/Jellyfish.jpg","actor":"anandan","actoress":"anandan","director":"anandan","music_director":"anandan","release_date":"March 18, 2015","tags":"movie 1,movie 1 ","age_restriction":"14","box_office":"36985214","official_site":"http://google.com","duration":"1.50 hr","writers":"anandan","imdb":8,"status":"1","language":"Tamil","created":"2015-03-11 05:11:31","modified":"2015-03-25 10:12:39","movie_category_id":"Action","slug":"movie 1 ","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":0,"movie_details_url":"http://popcorn.pk/launch/Movies/view/1"},"fetch_timing":[{"id":"24","theater_name":"SOZO WORLD CINEMA","address":"Fortress Stadium, Lahore - Cantt, Lahore, Pakistan","show_times":["5:00 pm"],"screen_id":"29","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"25","theater_name":"ATRIUM CINEMA","address":"3rd Floor, Atrium Mall, 249 Staff Lines, Zaibunnisa Street, Saddar.  Karachi, Pakistan","show_times":["2:00 pm"],"screen_id":"30","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"28","theater_name":"CINEPAX - CITY AUDITORIUM","address":"Opposite Meezan Bank Regional Office at Ayesha Manzil, FB Area Block 14,Karachi,Pakistan","show_times":["3:15 pm","8:45 pm"],"screen_id":"33","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"29","theater_name":"NUEPLEX","address":"The Place, Khayaban e Shaheen Phase 8, D.H.A","show_times":["4:15 pm","11:30 am"],"screen_id":"34","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"30","theater_name":"CENTAURUS CINEPLEX","address":"Centaurus Mall, 1 Jinnah Avenue, 4th Floor Centaurus, F-8 Islamabad","show_times":["10:45 pm","11:45 am","5:30 pm"],"screen_id":"35","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"32","theater_name":"CINE MOOSH","address":"House no. A/18, Unit no.3, Main AutoBhan Road, Latifabad, Hyderabad","show_times":["12:00 pm","11:15 pm","6:15 pm"],"screen_id":"37","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"33","theater_name":"CINEGOLD PLEX","address":"Main Boulevard, Garden City, between Phase 7 & 8, Expressway, Rawalpindi 46000","show_times":["12:15 pm"],"screen_id":"38","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"34","theater_name":"CINEPAX JINNAH PARK","address":"Cinepax Jinnah Park Kachehri Road, Rawalpindi \u00e2\u20ac\u201c Pakistan","show_times":["3:00 pm","10:30 pm","8:00 pm","1:00 am","5:30 pm"],"screen_id":"39","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"35","theater_name":"CINEPAX HOTEL ONE","address":"Hotel One 99/C, Peoples Colony (Near D Ground) Faisalabad","show_times":["3:00 pm","8:15 pm","1:45 am"],"screen_id":"40","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"36","theater_name":"SUPER CINEMA","address":"Vogue Tower, MM Alam road, Lahore","show_times":["2:30 pm"],"screen_id":"41","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"37","theater_name":"SUPER CINEMA - SHABISTAN","address":"Shahbistan and Prince, Abbot road Lahore","show_times":["1:00 pm","4:00 pm","8:00 pm"],"screen_id":"42","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"38","theater_name":"CINE STAR","address":"Plot #13,2 civic center township Lahore","show_times":["1:00 am","7:30 pm"],"screen_id":"43","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"39","theater_name":"TAJ CINEMA","address":"Plot #13,2 civic center township Lahore","show_times":["2:30 pm","8:00 pm"],"screen_id":"44","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"40","theater_name":"CINESTAR IMAX","address":"Plot #13,2 civic center township Lahore","show_times":["2:00 pm","7:30 pm"],"screen_id":"45","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"41","theater_name":"Taj Mahal Multiplex","address":"Taj Mahal Multiplex Cinemas, Railway Road, Faisalabad-38000","show_times":["4:00 pm","10:00 pm","7:00 pm"],"screen_id":"46","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"44","theater_name":"DHA Cinema","address":"305-R Block, D.H.A, Lahore Pakistan","show_times":["1:00 am","7:30 pm"],"screen_id":"49","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"47","theater_name":"Imperial Cinemas","address":"Imperial Garden Homes, Lahore, Pakistan","show_times":["12:50 am","2:30 pm","7:45 pm"],"screen_id":"52","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"48","theater_name":"CINEPAX GUJRANWALA","address":"Prince Cinepax Main G T Road, Gujranwala - Pakistan","show_times":["12:45 pm","3:15 pm","3:30 pm","11:00 pm","8:30 pm","12:30 pm","6:00 pm"],"screen_id":"53","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"49","theater_name":"Super Cinema - Gujrat","address":"Super Cinema Gujrat, Gt Road, Gujrat","show_times":["1:00 pm","7:00 pm"],"screen_id":"54","title":"Standard Screen"},{"id":"51","theater_name":"Capri Cinema","address":"Gazdarabad, Karachi, Pakistan, Karachi, Pakistan","show_times":["3:00 pm","9:00 pm","6:00 pm"],"screen_id":"56","title":"Standard Screen"}]}

How I call out to webservice 
          private async Task WCFRESTServiceCall(string methodRequestType, string methodName, string bodyParam = "")

```
        {
            try {
                string ServiceURI = "/app/webroot/launchwebservice/index.php/webservice/" + methodName;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(methodRequestType == "GET" ? HttpMethod.Get : HttpMethod.Post, ServiceURI);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyParam))
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(bodyParam, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                string jsongString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return jsongString;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                return "";            }
        }
    }
```

Then I call the method as so reference the fetching_time object I thought that would have been enough to do but its returning null for fetching time.

```
    public async Task<FetchTiming> GetMovieShowtimesAsync()
    {
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");
        var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FetchTiming>(jsonresult);


        return jarray;
    }
```

**Edit Done Above**

Ok I have done what he suggested and now I am showing as follows but now its just showing Any Ideas what I am doing wrong should I be saying {Binding Fetching_Time instead?

[image]

```
 private async void listViewShowtimes_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popcornpk_Dal _dal = new popcornpk_Dal();
        MovieDetail _showTimes = await _dal.GetMovieShowtimesAsync();

        var listView = (ListView)sender;

        listView.ItemsSource = _showTimes.fetch_timing;

    }
```

**Edit 2**

I should have explained I already have that that is why I am getting the error obv

```
  <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ListView x:Name="listViewShowtimes" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Loaded="listViewShowtimes_Loaded">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Height="505">

                            <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtshowtime"  Text="{Binding  theater_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtshow_times"  Text="{Binding show_times}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
```

Please see below it is seeing the data now but not parsing it I need the show times to show in a list below the cinema name [image]

Answer (score 0):

You call to a service that returns you the entire `MovieDetail` class, but you're trying to deserialize it to the `FetchTiming` class.

Simply deserialize the string to the `MovieDetail` class, and get the timing array from it.

Comment: how would i parse the timming array from it ?

Comment: can you provide example and I will make urs as the answer please

Comment: That's actually good, it means the data is coming as it should. Now what you're missing is the visual representation. When XAML encounters an element without visual representation (like your data class), it displays it's `ToString()` value, so you can use that for a quick and dirty way to display your data. If you want make it look better, you'll have to use [Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101.aspx) and [Data Templates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-Data-templates-and-tri).

Comment: Can you help me out here still haivng issues with this

Comment: Take a look at the debug output to see the binding exceptions, what are you getting there?

Comment: thjier is no issue its getting it i just dontt no how to parse the showtimes in the binding attribue

Comment: please see the new screen shot below the other one i need showtimes to be showing in a list below cinema name but how ?

Comment: You need to add a new listbox instead of the second textblock and bind the times collection to it.